# Posting on my Facebook page from my app: Facebook login doesn't want to grant permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have a Facebook page (I'm the admin) and a Facebook app (I'm the developer) and through this app I want to post on this page.

Via https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth I'm trying to grant to my app the manage_pages permission of my page. But an error pops up:

"Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook. Submit for review now or learn more."

If I click on "ok" I obtain the access token (and then the fb_exchange_token) but, as the pop up says, something goes wrong: the app isn't able to post on the page ("The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action").

Why is this?

Comment: You need `publish_actions` permission as well to be able to post stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, that error message states the user hasn't authorized to post (perform this action). You need to grant `publish_actions` and you need to use the page token to post to call as well.